# How to convert a list of genes to one element per row?

Tags: go-enrichment

I got two lists of about 300 genes from my GO analysis, like the following:

```
Mtss1/Sox11/Fbn2/Mmp2/Tcf7l2/Six2/Ahr/Fat4/Lef1/Stc1/Acvr2a/Glis1/Nog/Igsf10/Twist2/Igf1/...
```

How can I convert the list to one element per row (for Venn diagram  on Venny 2.1), as:

```
Mtss1
Sox11
Fbn2
Mmp2
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "Mtss1/Sox11/Fbn2/Mmp2/..." | tr '/' '\n' > list.txt
```

For more information on `tr`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)

Comment: It works well in my terminal, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In R you can use `tidyr`'s function `separate_rows`.

```
install.packages("tidyr") ## if not already installed
library(tidyr)
GO_results<-read.table("genes.txt")
separate_rows(GO_results, GO_results$V1, sep = "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways, assuming you're on a *nix system.

1. `tr`. Alex [already gave you](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/10503/298) a fine `tr` solution, but here's another approach assuming you have an input file:

   ```
   tr / '\n' < golist.txt > newlist.txt
   ```
2. `sed`

   ```
   sed 's|/|\n|g' golist.txt > newlist.txt
   ```

   Or, to edit the original file:

   ```
   sed -i 's|/|\n|g' golist.txt
   ```
3. Perl

   ```
   perl -pe 's|/|\n|g' golist.txt > newlist.txt
   ```

   Or, to edit the original file:

   ```
   perl -i -pe 's|/|\n|g' golist.txt
   ```
4. `grep` (GNU `grep`, the default on Linux systems)

   ```
   grep -Eo '[^/]+' golist.txt > newlist.txt
   ```

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: @Lin you're very welcome. If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites. Since Alex answered first, you might want to accept his.